# Is There A Way To Merge Joi Schemas?

Tags: validation, object, merge, joi

Is there any way to merge two joi schemas into a single schema?

Schema 1

```
{
  alpha: Joi.number().required(),
  beta: Joi.string().required(),
  chalie: Joi.object({
    xray: Joi.number().required(),
  }).required()
}
```

Schema 1

```
{
  delta: Joi.string().required(),
  echo: Joi.number().required(),
  charlie: Joi.object({
    zulu: Joi.string().required(),
  }).required()
}
```

Merged Schema:

```
{
  alpha: Joi.number().required(),
  beta: Joi.string().required(),
  chalie: Joi.object({
    xray: Joi.number().required(),
    zulu: Joi.string().required(),
  }).required()
  delta: Joi.string().required(),
  echo: Joi.number().required(),
}
```

Without nested objects it's easily done with `Object.assign`, but even a deep object merge won't work with the nested objects because the nested object is a function call.

Comment: You may be able to create your own function using a combination of `Object.assign()` and `Joi`'s [`concat()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyconcatschema)

Answer (score 18):

I was wondering the same thing, as I wanted to merge two different schemas, and found this: https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v9.0.4/API.md#anyconcatschema

```js
const a = Joi.string().valid('a');
const b = Joi.string().valid('b');
const ab = a.concat(b);
```

Hope that helps you

Answer (score 12):

Did you try Joi.append?

https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.5.2/API.md#objectkeysschema

```
// Validate key a
const base = Joi.object().keys({
    a: Joi.number()
});

// Validate keys a, b.
const extended = base.append({
    b: Joi.string()
});
```

UPDATED (2020-05-03):

An easy way to accomplish that would be like this:

```
var base = Joi.object({ firstname: Joi.string() });
var fullName = base.keys({ lastName: Joi.number() });
```

Comment: That results in `AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Object schema cannot be a joi schema` if you try to append a schema

Answer (score 6):

Using plain javascript objects was not an option for me. I tried using the `.keys` method to extend but it overwrites existing keys (for charlie in this case).

The solution I settled on was using `.reach`:
Example:

```
const Joi = require('joi');
const originalSchema = Joi.object({
  a: { 
    deep: {
      b: Joi.string()
    }    
  },
  c: Joi.string()
});
const extendedSchema = Joi.object({
  a: { 
    deep: Joi
      .reach(originalSchema, 'a.deep')
      .keys({ anotherB: Joi.string() })
  },
  c: Joi.reach(originalSchema, 'c')
});

// No errors
extendedSchema.validate({ a: { deep: { b: 'hi', anotherB: 'hi' } }, c: 'wow' })
```

Answer (score 5):

`Joi.object()` and the spread operator `...` did the trick for me. (Joi version 17)

```js
import * as Joi from 'joi'

const childSchema: {
    PORT: Joi.number(),
}

const parentSchema = Joi.object({
    NODE_ENV: Joi.string(),
    APP_NAME: Joi.string(),
    ...childSchema,
})
```

Comment: using version 17.6.2 here, `.append` was throwing an `undefined` error. This spread operator trick worked for me as well

Answer (score 2):

I didn't like any of the answers here, so I found a different method. I created a class so I could set a single rule for an item, like an email address or password with a single point of origin for the requirements, rather than multiple schemas in different files. or even multiple semi-redundant schemas within a single file/class.

Worth noting that .append doesn't work if the first rule is empty. This is where .concat comes in.

First I built a class with a couple single item rules

```
//an email address
  static emailAddress = Joi.object({
    emailAddress: Joi.string()
      .email({ tlds: { allow: false } })
      .required()
      .label("Email Address"),
  });

  static passwordRegex = /^(?=.*[A-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()])\S{8,}$/;
  static passwordError =
    "Password must be at least 8 characters long, and have at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number, and one special character.";
  
  //a password
  static password = Joi.object({
    password: Joi.string()
      .min(8)
      .regex(this.passwordRegex)
      .message(this.passwordError)
      .label("Password"),
  });
```

Then I created a couple of rules for specific objects I needed to check.

```
static registerUserSchema() {
    let schema = Joi.object()
      .concat(this.yourNameSchema)
      .concat(this.emailAddress)
      .concat(this.password)
      .concat(this.confirmPassword);
    return schema;
  }
```

Took me forever to figure out, but this works flawlessly.

Comment: This should be considered the right answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension of @szanata answer, this is a working example of merging multiple schemas used to validate a request body. I created this as a middleware for routes and sometimes have up to 3 schemas validating a request body. You can pass a single schema, or array of schemas.

```
const validateRequest = (schema) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
  if(Array.isArray(schema)){
    let schemas = schema;
    schema = schemas[0]
    schemas.forEach((s, idx) => {
      if (idx > 0) schema = schema.concat(s);
    });
  }
  let data = { ...req.body, ...req.query, ...req.params };
  const { error } = schema.validate(data, options);

  if (error) res.status(422).json({msg:`${error.details.map((x) => x.message).join(", ")}`})
  else next();
  }
}
```

Example usage as middleware for route:

```
const { query, mongoDbId, test } = require("../utils/validation-schema");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/test", protect, validateInput([mongoDbId, test, query]), 
(req, res) => {
res.json({ msg: "OK" });
});
```

Output of console.log(schema._ids) after concat.

```
{
 _byId: Map {},
 _byKey: Map {
 '_id' => { schema: [Object], id: '_id' },
 'databaseType' => { schema: [Object], id: 'databaseType' },
 'host' => { schema: [Object], id: 'host' },
 'database' => { schema: [Object], id: 'database' },
 'user' => { schema: [Object], id: 'user' },
 'password' => { schema: [Object], id: 'password' },
 'datasource' => { schema: [Object], id: 'datasource' },
 'sql' => { schema: [Object], id: 'sql' },
 'modifier' => { schema: [Object], id: 'modifier' },
 'sqlType' => { schema: [Object], id: 'sqlType' },
 'format' => { schema: [Object], id: 'format' },
 'timeout' => { schema: [Object], id: 'timeout' }
 },
 _schemaChain: false
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, you can simplify the concatenation code a bit by using `reduce`: `const concatenatedSchemas = schema.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b), Joi.any())`

Answer (score -1):

While you can use Javascript's `Object.assign()`, I think what you're looking for is Joi's [`.keys()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectkeysschema)  function.

In your code, I'd do:

```
const schema1 = Joi.object({
  alpha: Joi.number().required(),
  beta: Joi.string().required(),
  charlie: Joi.object({
    xray: Joi.number().required(),
  }).required()
});

const schema2 = Joi.object({
  delta: Joi.string().required(),
  echo: Joi.number().required(),
  charlie: Joi.object({
    zulu: Joi.string().required(),
  }).required()
});

const mergedSchema = schema1.keys(schema2);
```

There's also an [interesting note](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#-notation) about using straight JS objects vs wrapping them in `Joi.object()`;

> When using the {} notation, you are just defining a plain JS object, which isn't a schema object. You can pass it to the validation method but you can't call validate() method of the object because it's just a plain JS object.
>
> Besides, passing the {} object to the validate() method each time, will perform an expensive schema compilation operation on every validation.
>
> When you use Joi.object([schema]), it gets compiled the first time, so you can pass it to the validate() method multiple times and no overhead is added.

So you could take [Ankh's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2043204/ankh) suggestion and use straight JS objects:

```
const schema1 = {
  alpha: Joi.number().required(),
  beta: Joi.string().required(),
  charlie: Joi.object({
    xray: Joi.number().required(),
  }).required()
};

const schema2 ={
  delta: Joi.string().required(),
  echo: Joi.number().required(),
  charlie: Joi.object({
    zulu: Joi.string().required(),
  }).required()
};

const mergedSchema = Object.assign({}, schema1, schema2);
```

but there's an associated performance penalty.

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v15.0.1/API.md#objectappendschema

> **object.append([schema])**
>   Appends the allowed object keys where:
>
> schema - optional object where each key is assigned a joi type object. If schema is null,undefined or {} no changes will be applied. Uses object.keys([schema]) to append keys.
>
> ```
> // Validate key a
> const base = Joi.object().keys({
>     a: Joi.number()
> });
> // Validate keys a, b.
> const extended = base.append({
>     b: Joi.string()
> });
> ```

Comment: @Undistraction it's actually a copy-paste from the doc: https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v15.0.1/API.md#objectappendschema

Comment: does not work for joi version 17, it returns "Error: Object schema cannot be a joi schema"